# how do I identify this bolt for local purchase?

Tags: fastener

This comes off of a DeWalt Powerwasher DP3750.  The Dewalt part number is 18300.  Specifications are 375-16X1.75 FL.  They want 7 bucks for this bolt online.

[image: Full Frontal Shot] [image: Head shot.]

Drilling down here (to find later at fastenal) closest I can seem to come is this one.

https://www.boltdepot.com/Product-Details.aspx?product=17258

What's giving me pause is another bolt that is on the power washer has a "10" stamped on the head of it.  I can't find that anywhere.  The bolt holds the pump onto the engine.

Any ideas how to get this locally?

Comment: Can you add photos?

Comment: The '10' stamped on the end is the grade of the metal. If you have another example of the bolt you need, take it to a hardware store and look around until you find a match. They will usually have tools to tell you the exact size, but if they don't find a nut that threads on so you know what diameter and thread pitch you're looking for. If you can't find correct shoulder length, you can always get a longer bolt with the correct shoulder and trim off the threaded section to match. Good luck!

Comment: I figured given the application of it a hardware store wouldn't be a good spot ?

Comment: I'd just take it to my local hardware store and get them to work out the thread pitch, length and diameter.  I'm sure they'd have something which would fit.

Comment: I use a local industrial supply shop (DFW area) that has just about every permutation of bolt that you can imagine, typically costs less than a quarter for a single bolt. Google "Industrial supply" in your area and see what you can come up with. Hardware stores may have what you're looking for, though not always in the same grade, etc.

Comment: update on this.  come to find out the bolt i pulled shouldn't have been in there to start with.  a local small-shop hardware store matched it up and gave me one of the bolts that i pulled out and one that matched DeWalts specs - the DeWalt one fit.  go figure.  now i'm going to pull the pump off and see how things look inside.

Answer (score 2):

Ace Hardware has always blown me away with the odd bolts they carry. Really they have most everything- or at least something that can be made to work.

Ebay is also an excellent option for some of the oddest bolts out there.

Between those two you should be able to find almost anything.

$7 really isn't so bad. I've had to just deal with paying $20+ for odd bolts. Low supply, low demand makes it impractical and expensive to stock.

If all else fails, there's always duct tape ;)

Comment: ha, well I don't think duct tape is good to hold a pump onto the engine but it did make me think of the local guy - not big-box like home depot.  These guys have a lot of odds and ends.  worth a shot.

Comment: Well, now we're both armchair philosophers until one of us wraps an engine in 8 layers of duct tape.

Comment: this is probably not allowed - but LMAO

Comment: The ACE Hardware bolt section is gold.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same as my Dewalt powered by a Honda Gx200, it should be a M8 x 1.0 metric fine bolt.  With about 2.5cm thread length.
This should be found at any well stocked hardware store or any good auto parts store.
My bolts are standard head with a lock washer.  Yours appear to be a flange with I suspect a serrated face for locking.