# Who Makes or Sources helmet screws for a MSR Xpedition motorcycle helmet?

Tags: motorcycle, crash-helmet

I have a MSR Xpedition motorcycle helmet. It's rather cheaply made, and one of the side screws that holds the visor on fell out.

Any ideas on where I can get a replacement screw? I have reached out to the OEM customer service via e-mail, to see if I can get one from them.  Is there another source for this part you know of?

Comment: Do you have a picture of what the screw looks like?

Comment: This might help point you in the right direction: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/37027/how-do-i-identify-this-bolt-for-local-purchase

Comment: jafrum web site has them

Comment: http://www.sportbiketrackgear.com/msr-xpedition-screw-kit/

Comment: You're asking the wrong question.  It will be impossible to get an OEM screw.  Follow @MooseLucifer's link to identify the bolt.  Then you can buy any generic 2-cent bolt from anywhere.

Comment: Asking where to get a replacement screw is the "wrong question?" Haha, alright. :)

Comment: @TrevorSullivan  The reason relates to shopping assistance.  If someone posted a link to a website, that website may change it's URL path to the product or it may become obsolete.  It falls under the category of 'shopping assistance'.